# Check for duplicates in for loop before entity manager is flushed

Tags: symfony, duplicates, entitymanager

I have a data source that I'm using a for loop to process. The data source can sometimes have duplicates. I'm looping over the data source and creating "item" entities. I'm trying to avoid those duplicates but I think that since the items have not been sent to the database they are not found during the duplicate check.

Here is my **pseudo** for loop:

```
foreach($datasource['data'] as $post){
    $dupe = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->findOneByDatasourceId($post['id']);
    if(!$dupe){
        //process the item
        $item = new Item();
        $item->setDatasourceId($post['id']);
        $em->persist($item);
    }
}

$em->flush();
```

This does find duplicates.

How do I find duplicates when the data has not been sent to the database yet? I was under the impression that the entity manager would have known about the data that has yet to be pushed.

Thanks

Comment: if you flush after persist you have duplicates? of course is not an optimised solution but you can store in an local temporary array the insered id and check in this array also.

Comment: I think that @Matteo's solution is the best to performance, however you can use `UniqueEntity` constraint in `Item` entity and validate it before `persist()` by using `validator` service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EntityManager::find does not check items waiting to be persisted.  The items are stored in a unit of work object and, in theory, you could check it.  But it's a bit of a pain.  As @Matteo has suggested, You could also flush after each persist but that can impact performance.

It's easy enough to make you own local cache:

```
$datasourceCache = [];
foreach($datasource['data'] as $post){
    $postId = $post['id'];
    if (!isset($datasourceCache[$postID] (
        $datasourceCache[$postID] = true;
        $dupe = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Item')->findOneByDatasourceId($postId);
        if(!$dupe){
            //process the item
            $item = new Item();
            $item->setDatasourceId($postId);
            $em->persist($item);
        }
    }
}
$em->flush();
```